# Map within a map in terraform variables

Tags: variables, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Does anyone know if it's possible with possibly code snipits representing whether I can create a map variable within a map variable in terraform variables?

```
variable "var" {
  type = map
  default = {
    firstchoice = {
      firstAChoice ="foo"
      firstBChoice = "bar"
    }
    secondchoice = {
      secondAChoice = "foobar"
      secondBChoice = "barfoo"
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone has any insight to whether this is possible or any documentation that elaborates that would be great.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have map variable as value of map variable key. Your variable just needed right indentation. Also I am putting ways to access that variable.

```
variable "var" {
  default = {
    firstchoice = {
      firstAChoice = "foo"
      firstBChoice = "bar"
    }

    secondchoice = {
      secondAChoice = "foobar"
      secondBChoice = "barfoo"
    }
  }
}
```

To access entire map value of a map key `firstchoice`, you can try following

```
value = "${var.var["firstchoice"]}"

output:
{
  firstAChoice = foo
  firstBChoice = bar
}
```

To access specific key of that map key (example `firstAChoice`), you can try

```
value = "${lookup(var.var["firstchoice"],"firstAChoice")}"

output: foo
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a ton!

Comment: Would this syntax be possible? ${var.var[firstchoice[firstAchoice]]}

Comment: I only ask because I have need of a third tier map

Comment: What type do you need to set for this kind of variable?

Answer (score 11):

> Would this syntax be possible? ${var.var[firstchoice[firstAchoice]]}

With Terraform 0.12+ nested blocks are supported seamlessly. Extending @Avichal Badaya's answer to explain it using an example:

```
# Nested Variable

variable "test" {
  default = {
    firstchoice = {
      firstAChoice = "foo"
      firstBChoice = "bar"
    }

    secondchoice = {
      secondAChoice = "foobar"
      secondBChoice = "barfoo"
    }

    thirdchoice = {
      thirdAChoice = {
          thirdBChoice = {
              thirdKey = "thirdValue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


# Outputs

output "firstchoice" {
  value = var.test["firstchoice"]
}

output "FirstAChoice" {
  value = var.test["firstchoice"]["firstAChoice"]
}

output "thirdKey" {
  value = var.test["thirdchoice"]["thirdAChoice"]["thirdBChoice"]["thirdKey"]
}
```

Applying the above, you can verify that Terraform map nesting is now quite powerful and this makes a lot of things easier.

```
# Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

# Outputs:

firstchoice = {
  "firstAChoice" = "foo"
  "firstBChoice" = "bar"
}

thirdKey = thirdValue
```

For more complex structures and Rich Value Types, see [HashiCorp Terraform 0.12 Preview: Rich Value Types](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-rich-value-types)

Comment: I like this updated answer. It makes the code a lot more readable. Would it be possible to traverse the map using the dot notation? For example: `var.test.firstchoice.firstAchoice`?

Comment: Yes. You can give it a try using `terraform console` (https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/console)